# Why does pipenv fail to install a package inside a docker container

Tags: python, docker, pipenv

Follows a Dockerfile for the sake of reproducibility:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# pipenv install numpy pybind11 mako pyopencl

ENV PYTHONFAULTHANDLER=1 \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONHASHSEED=random \
    PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on \
    PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
    PIPENV_HIDE_EMOJIS=true \
    PIPENV_COLORBLIND=true \
    PIPENV_NOSPIN=true \
    PYTHONPATH=/app \
    LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 \
    LANG=C.UTF-8 \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

WORKDIR ${PYTHONPATH}
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        python3-pip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN pip3 install pipenv
```

Which can be built with:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t pipenv_issue .
```

And run with:

```
docker run --rm -it pipenv_issue:latest bash
```

Inside which you can try:

```
pipenv install numpy
```

Which will fail with:

```
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Pipfile: /app/Pipfile
Using /usr/bin/python3 (3.5.2) to create virtualenv…
Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.

Virtualenv location: /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q
Creating a Pipfile for this project…
Installing numpy…

Adding numpy to Pipfile's [packages]…
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
Updated Pipfile.lock (5a67c1)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (5a67c1)…
An error occurred while installing numpy==1.16.0 --hash=sha256:00a458d6821b1e87be873f2126d5646b901047a7480e8ae9773ecf214f0e19f3 --hash=sha256:0470c5dc32212a08ebc2405f32e8ceb9a5b1c8ac61a2daf9835ec0856a220495 --hash=sha256:24a9c287a4a1c427c2d45bf7c4fc6180c52a08fa0990d4c94e4c86a9b1e23ba5 --hash=sha256:25600e8901012180a1b7cd1ac3e27e7793586ecd432383191929ac2edf37ff5d --hash=sha256:2d279bd99329e72c30937bdef82b6dc7779c7607c5a379bab1bf76be1f4c1422 --hash=sha256:32af2bcf4bb7631dac19736a6e092ec9715e770dcaa1f85fcd99dec5040b2a4d --hash=sha256:3e90a9fce378114b6c2fc01fff7423300515c7b54b7cc71b02a22bc0bd7dfdd8 --hash=sha256:5774d49516c37fd3fc1f232e033d2b152f3323ca4c7bfefd7277e4c67f3c08b4 --hash=sha256:64ff21aac30d40c20ba994c94a08d439b8ced3b9c704af897e9e4ba09d10e62c --hash=sha256:803b2af862dcad6c11231ea3cd1015d1293efd6c87088be33d713a9b23e9e419 --hash=sha256:95c830b09626508f7808ce7f1344fb98068e63143e6050e5dc3063142fc60007 --hash=sha256:96e49a0c82b4e3130093002f625545104037c2d25866fa2e0c90d6e54f5a1fbc --hash=sha256:a1dd8221f0e69038748f47b8bb3248d0b9ecdf13fe837440951c3d5ff72639bb --hash=sha256:a80ecac5664f420556a725a5646f2d1c60a7c0489d68a38b5056393e949e27ac --hash=sha256:b19a47ff1bd2fca0cacdfa830c967746764c32dca6a0c0328d9c893f4bfe2f6b --hash=sha256:be43df2c563e264b38e3318574d80fc8f365df3fb745270934d2dbe54e006f41 --hash=sha256:c40cb17188f6ae3c5b6efc6f0fd43a7ddd219b7807fe179e71027849a9b91afc --hash=sha256:c6251e0f0ecac53ba2b99d9f0cc16fa9021914a78869c38213c436ba343641f0 --hash=sha256:cb189bd98b2e7ac02df389b6212846ab20661f4bafe16b5a70a6f1728c1cc7cb --hash=sha256:ef4ae41add536cb825d8aa029c15ef510aead06ea5b68daea64f0b9ecbff17db --hash=sha256:f00a2c21f60284e024bba351875f3501c6d5817d64997a0afe4f4355161a8889 --hash=sha256:f1232f98a6bbd6d1678249f94028bccc541bbc306aa5c4e1471a881b0e5a3409 --hash=sha256:fea682f6ddc09517df0e6d5caad9613c6d91a42232aeb082df67e4d205de19cc! Will try again.
Installing initially failed dependencies…
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1992, in do_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       skip_lock=skip_lock,
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1253, in do_init
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 859, in do_install_dependencies
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       retry_list, procs, failed_deps_queue, requirements_dir, **install_kwargs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 763, in batch_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       _cleanup_procs(procs, not blocking, failed_deps_queue, retry=retry)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 681, in _cleanup_procs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       raise exceptions.InstallError(c.dep.name, extra=err_lines)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['Collecting numpy==1.16.0 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-6etsbc3u-requirements/pipenv-rs8asrue-requirement.txt (line 1))', '  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/64/24/2e9c72f44cec8c872000d78c54230e40550c494647e352d1d06724cdaee6/numpy-1.16.0-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (17.2MB)']
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['Exception:', 'Traceback (most recent call last):', '  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 176, in main', '    status = self.run(options, args)', '  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 346, in run', '    session=session, autobuilding=True', '  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/wheel.py", line 848, in build', '    assert building_is_possible', 'AssertionError']
ERROR: ERROR: Package installation failed...
```

Why does it fail?

Thanks in advance.

---

Comment: Ok I Guess, I found the problem. When You go to this https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/7696e7e5303b23d233097cf26749bc1e4a5e0645/src/pip/_internal/wheel.py You will see thats Your pip is using this version of pip. But there is also an annotation in this code ` # TODO: This check fails if --no-cache-dir is set` and as I see You are using the flag `PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off` but according to the doc `To enable the boolean options --no-compile and --no-cache-dir, falsy values have to be used` so In your case this is set so as this TODO says it will fail-> proposed solution. upgrade or change env

Comment: Take_Care_: Very helpful your comment.
It is interesting though, that turning the flag `PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=on` won't solve the problem. But commenting out will.

Comment: This comment explains why this happens https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/src/pip/_internal/wheel.py#L843

Comment: This just started happening for me as well (and I see the question and comments are very recent, too), so something must have changed. Maybe in pipenv?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behavior was a bug and should be fixed by upgrading to pip v19.0.1

https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6158#issuecomment-456814568

Comment: Got this bug with pip v20 in python:alpine docker container.

Answer (score 4):

#### To make a summary from comments :

The Problem exists because of the check condition in the `wheel.py` in `pip` sources. To resolve this problem there is already `TODO` comment added to sources.

> `TODO: This check fails if --no-cache-dir is set.`
>
> `And yet we might be able to build into the ephemeral cache, surely?`

Linkt at master provided [intsco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3801411/intsco)

but for future changes there is link to first appearnce of this [TODO 1st detected](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/b62284a81ba5baf73d423ec08c1ad45d1a9d761d/src/pip/_internal/wheel.py#L769).

#### Current solution :

as OP mentioned

**comment** the `PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem during a build today.
In my Dockerfile, which has python and pip preinstalled (I'm using `python:3.6-slim-jessie` docker image) I have the line `pip install --upgrade setuptools pip` and today my build failed because of the new version upgrade.

**My Solution:**

I commented the line `pip install --upgrade setuptools pip` in my Dockerfile.

Works fine now.

In your case, this problem occurs when virtualenv is created. During creation, it installs the latest versions of setuptools, pip, wheel (see the line: `Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.`). Downgrading to previous pip, wheel, setuptools versions will help.

Comment: Perhaps you could share some logs, and maybe your Dockerfile(?) So we can check how similar your problem is. At first sight this seems to be completely unrelated. I am tempted to down vote your answer...

Comment: It happens when I install additional packages for spacy:
`Downloading https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz (37.4MB)`

Comment: `Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 176, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 346, in run
    session=session, autobuilding=True
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/wheel.py", line 848, in build
    assert building_is_possible
AssertionError`

Comment: I wrote: 'this problem occurs when virtualenv is created' but it's not quite right, sory - problem is on package installation step with additional data downloading. This happens with pip version 19. With version 18.1 installation works fine.